# Converting a list of arrays into a single list of elements in python

Tags: python, arrays

I would like to convert a list of arrays into a single list of elements.

I have this list of arrays:

```
[array([ 1.65988671]), array([ 1.66663357]), array([ 1.53351122]), array([ 1.60234953])]
```

and I would like to have this:

```
[1.6153020312169204, 1.6843892323785852, 1.662793812752394, 1.6332755497183022].
```

I used:

```
List=[]
for i in range(arr)):
    List.append(arr[i].tolist())
```

But I get this `[[ 1.65988671]), [ 1.66663357], [ 1.53351122], [ 1.60234953]]`

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: can't test it but try ...tolist()[0]

Comment: The floats in your input and expected output appear to be completely different.

Comment: @ajr they are two different list; i would like to have the shape of the second one

Comment: @user3841581 You misunderstand. It is being assumed that you want to extract the floats out of the first list, but your example input has the first float as `1.65988671` and the "matching" float from the output is `1.6153020312169204` which is a different number entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `my_list.extend` not `my_list.append`, and it should do what you want.

Comment: This works perfectly without any assumption. Thank you @ Isogen74

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arr = [
    np.array([ 1.65988671]), 
    np.array([ 1.66663357]), 
    np.array([ 1.53351122]), 
    np.array([ 1.60234953])]
    my_list = []
    for x in arr:
        my_list.append(x[0])
```

This works for me.

Comment: array is also available in the `array` module. `from array import array` `a=array('f', (1,2,3,4))` `for f in a: print f` produces `1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a list comprehension:

```
[item for arr in list_with_arrays for item in arr.tolist()]
```

Also you can use hstack:

```
list_with_arrays = [np.array([1, 2]), np.array([2, 3]), np.array([5, 6, 7])]
np.hstack(list_with_arrays).tolist()

[1, 2, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am by no means an expert and this may not make sense nor be the best way. But it works.

The way you are going about it you are appending each list in to a new list and therefore keeping them as a list. By adding each item to a new list (concatenating) it works.

I have even added some extra data to one of the lists to ensure it works.

```
start = [[ 1.65988671,1.7890], [ 1.66663357], [ 1.53351122], [ 1.60234953]]
target=[]
for i in range(len(start)):
        target = target+start[i]
print (target)
```

Comment: I tend to prefer [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) to the `range(len(a))` construct. The latter is less readable (to me) and can cause off-by-1 errors.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use `array` from the `array` module in python's standard library

```
from array import array
arr = [array('f', [ 1.65988671]), array('f', [ 1.66663357]), array('f', [ 1.53351122]), array('f', [ 1.60234953])]
lst = [ae for el in arr for ae in el]
```

produces

```
[1.6598867177963257, 1.6666336059570312, 1.5335111618041992, 1.6023495197296143]
```